# Project asking for a config setting that's there already

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, visual-studio-2010, config

Here is the code that I am calling:

```
try
{
    using (var client = new WCFServiceChannelFactory<IFxCurveService>())
    {
        guid = client.Call(svc => svc.ReserveSnapshot(fxCurveKey));
        DiscountFactorNew[] dfs = client.Call(svc => svc.GetDiscountFactors(guid, dates, from));
        return (double)dfs[0].Value;
    }
}
catch
{
    throw new Exception();
}
```

Now it can't instantiate the `WCFServiceFactory` because it can't find one of the .config keys that we require, however, it's there in the app.config.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ConfigurationServiceAddress" value="http://ksintapp:91/configurationservice.svc/mex" />
</appSettings>
```

This file and the file that are calling it are within the same directory. They are the only two files in the project, which is the only project in the solution.

This is the error:

> Failed to initialize configuration repository because an application
>   setting with the key 'ConfigurationServiceAddress' could not be found
>   in the local configuration file.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the setting in the `MyApp.exe.config` file that you're using?

Comment: No but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out by changing the service creation to this:

```
using (var client = new WCFServiceChannelFactory<IFxCurveService>(new Uri("http://ksqcoreapp64int:5025/")))
```

But now I'm having different issues, but at least I got around not needing a config file.

Answer (score 1):

If this is an executable application (Console, WinForms, WPF) make sure that the config file is called `AppName.exe.config` and is located in the same directory as `AppName.exe` where `AppName` is the name of the project. If it is a web application make sure that this setting is present in the `web.config`.

When you add an `App.config` file to a project of type executable in Visual Studio everytime you build it copies to the output directory (bin/Debug or bin/Release) this config file by renaming it to `AppName.exe.config` so that at runtime the application is able to resolve it.

Comment: It's not an executable application. It's a compiled DLL that Excel references to be able to create UDF's.

Comment: @slandau, wow, that's gonna be though. You need to create an `Excel.exe.config` in the same directory where Excel resides :-) Or find another location to store the url.

Comment: Same directory where Excel resides as in like c:\Program Files....etc.? Or in the same directory as the plugin?

Comment: I tried both and neither seem to work. Same error both times. When I try and pass in the Uri directly via the constructor, it gets past that line, but then says the service is in a faulted state... =/

Comment: @slandau, same directory where Excel.exe resides.

Answer (score 0):

A config file has to be loaded by the application that is hosting the code.  In your comments you state that this is an assembly that is loaded by excel.  You won't be able to create an excel.exe.config file that has any meaning.

So, you're left with explicitly stating what config file to load OR changing to using the registry.  I'd probably go with the latter while having that key defined in an install program.